# JavaScript validation on name field not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to make my form validation work but I somehow can't make my name field to validate properly. When I write names in the field it will say that I need to write a proper name. What am I doing wrong? HTML: http://pastebin.com/EfNSkQkS JavaScript: http://pastebin.com/c6iUCYvr

Comment: use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr7eafLn/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot to add the `+` sign at the end of your letters RegExp. i. e. `var reg_letters = /^[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]$/;` should be `var reg_letters = /^[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+$/;`

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your regex expression in your javascript code `var reg_letters = /^[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]$/;` I don't know what other characters you want to allow

But when i changed it this -->`var reg_letters = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;` it works(this regex expression is for English Characters only.

This is a plunker link to test it, just change them **(var reg-letters)** to test. [plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qtOOoy47QFWJxDmIliUD?p=preview)

*Note i removed the `action` and `method` from the form, so plunkr doesn't throw errors.

Comment: But what do I do if I need special characters such as æøå/ÆØÅ?

Comment: Okay i have updated the plunker for you, go and try it out. All i did was ```var reg_letters = /^[a-zA-Zæøå/ÆØÅ]*$/;```